# Best way to compare field against array of strings with Sequel Gem?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

If I need to check a field in a table against an array of possible strings (using Postgres with the Sequel gem), what's the fastest way to do so? I've tried building a regular expression from the array with `|`'s inbetween each entry, and then using it to search the table using `.where`, but it's slow... and I'm hoping there may be a faster way.

Answer (score 0):

If your field can be equal to one of multiple words, you can use :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IN ('apple', 'banana', 'carrot', 'dog', ....)
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL will probably not use an index for a regular expression lookup with `|`s, which would explain the slow speed on large datasets.  The `IN` operator is what you want to use, as it should be able to use an index lookup (assuming the appropriate index).  In Sequel:

```
DB[:table].where(:field=>['string1', 'string2', 'string3'])
```